# Plotting constant surface plot with `create_trisurf` of Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

Plotly seems to having no problem plotting non-constant surfaces but throws an error when one has a constant surface (uncomment `c.z=1`). How can this be fixed? I necessarily need to start with pandas dataframe with 3 columns. I don't know what the Delaunay part means really either.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

c = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,3)), columns = ['x', 'y', 'z'])
# c.z=1
points2D = np.vstack([c.x,c.y]).T
tri = Delaunay(points2D)
simplices = tri.simplices


fig = ff.create_trisurf(x=c.x, y=c.y, z=c.z,
                         simplices=simplices, 
                          aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.3))
fig.show()
```

PlotlyError: Incorrect relation between vmin and vmax. The vmin value cannot be bigger than or equal to the value of vmax.